# Как парсить и выводить JSON в HTML с помощью JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Приветствую.
Необходимо парсить JSON, который находится на другом сайте, а после читать этот json и выводить таблицей в html на сайт.
Думаю, что можно сделать это с помощью javascript методом JSON.parse, но никогда не работал с JavaScript и не нашел примера парсинга именно url сайта. 
И не до конца понимаю как выводить с помощью innerHTML \ outerHTML

Прошу помощи. Как проще это реализовать и если есть примеры, было бы идеально.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Какой у вас сервер?

Comment: Пока никакого, но думаю буду использовать VPS Amazonа

Comment: я спрашиваю не про машину (hardware), а про сервер/программу (software), который будет раздавать файлы и пр.

Comment: на Ubuntu 16.04.1 скорее всего

Comment: это всего лишь ОС - она сама не умеет раздавать файлы.

Comment: Веб-сервер Apache

Comment: то есть вы хотите парсить JSON на стороне клиента?

Comment: да, при каждом запросе

Comment: если сайт сторонний, то у вас не получиться из-за CORS.

Comment: Почему, если JSON API публичный

Comment: проверьте разрешает ли сервер запросы с любого адреса - Access-Control-Allow-Origin